# Differentiating between relevant and irrelevant URLs

Tags: python, url, python-3.x, web-scraping

So I'm trying to write a program that generates and opens a random news article from a list of news sites that I put in the program. The way I'm doing it is by pulling all the url links off of the front pages of each website and then picking one randomly to open. However, there are a few urls that are irrelevant and not linked to news articles, and I'm trying to think of good ways to filter them out. Do you guys have any suggestions? Right now I'm filtering them by checking to see if the url contains the url of the front page in it, which takes care of some but not all of the irrelevant URLs. It also filters out a lot of news articles based on what website I'm scraping from. Here's the code for reference.

```
    import webbrowser
    import urllib.request
    import random
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    news_sites_list = ["http://www.bbc.com","http://www.wired.com","http://www.howstuffworks.com","http://www.slashdot.org", "http://www.vice.com", "http://noisey.vice.com", "http://thecreatorsproject.vice.com"]

    def random_web_getter(newslist):
        randomlim = len(newslist)
        url = newslist[random.randint(0,randomlim-1)]
        connection = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        html = connection.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
        links = soup.find_all('a')
        linklist = []
        for tag in links:
            link = tag.get('href', None)
            if link != None and url in link:
                linklist.append(link)
        return linklist[random.randint(0, len(linklist)-1)]
        webbrowser.open(random_web_getter(news_sites_list), 1, True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than scraping the front page for news stories, why not get the RSS feed from each site and just use that?  Here's an example for the BBC "Top Stories" feed, which returns an XML document.  I'm using the requests, bs4 and webbrowser modules:

```
>>> page = requests.get('http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml')
>>> links = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text).find_all('link')
>>> print links[0].text
http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-32655943#sa-ns_mchannel=rss&ns_source=PublicRSS20-sa
>>> webbrowser.open(links[0].text)
```

I've now got an open web browser with the first link in the RSS feed being displayed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! If you don't mind me asking, what does .text do?

Comment: There are two instances: `page.text` and `links[0].text`.  If you do `type(page)` you'll see that it's referring to an object of type "requests.models.Response".  The text attribute just refers to a plain text (unicode) representation of the response - effectively, the content of the page.  The same goes for `links[0].text`.  The object is of type "bs4.element.Tag", and the text attribute refers to plain text (again, unicode) representing the content of the tag - basically the text "inside" the `<link></link>` tag.